# Working with pieces of text in python

Tags: python, regex

Data.txt includes words that are upper and lower-cased.

I need to `lower case them all except for the upper-cased characters that appear in braces` which are located immediately following a word that can end in either lower or upper case, but there is no space before the first brace. 
e.g.

```
CAT{TT} Dog{DD} Horse{AA}
Snail{LL} RAT{TT}
ANT{AA}
```

These should be transformed into:

```
cat{TT} dog{DD} horse{AA}
snail{LL} rat{TT}
ant{AA}
```

As a first start, I lower-cased everything in the list and placed them in `lcChar`(code as below). I was then trying to find the lower-cased characters within braces so that I could upper case them again.

Being a python newbie, I got stuck in my code below. This gives only the very first item in braces. Also I am assuming I need another loop in order to upper case all the items that appear in the braces. Any help please so I can understand the best methodology for handling these type of issues?

```
import re
f = open(r'C:\Python27\MyScripts\Data.txt')
for line in f:
    lcChar = (line.lower())

patFinder1 = re.compile('{[a-z]+}')
findPat1=re.findall(patFinder1, lcChar)
```

Comment: Explication unclear; Could you provide a short list of text and your expected output...

Comment: CAT{TT} Dog{DD} Horse{AA}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`re.sub` and `re.subn` allow the second parameter to be a function.  A Match Object is passed into that function and whatever the function returns is used for the substitution.

This is my take on it:

```
import re

def manip(m):
    return m.groups()[0].lower()

data = ['CAT{TT} Dog{DD} Horse{AA}',
        'Snail{LL} RAT{TT}',
        'ANT{AA}']

for line in data:
    new_line = re.sub(r'((?:[^{]|^)[A-Z]+(?:[^}]|$))', manip, line)
    print new_line
```

Produces:

```
cat{TT} dog{DD} horse{AA}
snail{LL} rat{TT}
ant{AA}
```

I could have used a `lambda` instead, but that's arguably less clear.

Answer (score 1):

A straight forward way of doing it:

```
import re

regex = re.compile('([^}]*?{)')
str_ = '''CAT{TT} Dog{DD} Horse{AA}
Snail{LL} RAT{TT}
ANT{AA}'''

new_str =  re.sub(regex, lambda match: match.groups()[0].lower(), str_)
assert new_str == '''cat{TT} dog{DD} horse{AA}
snail{LL} rat{TT}
ant{AA}'''

print new_str
```

#### Explaination:

I use the regex to only match what need to be lowercased:

[image]

Then I loop over the results and replace to lowercase version.

*Edit*: more optimize version using sub to replace.

Comment: thank you, @Cyrbil. Your code works beautifully. I got it to work with the file. I am reviewing how you composed ('[^}]*?{') that worked so well. Can you explain that please? That's what I was having difficulty with and decided to do the two-step approach above.

Comment: @angelica: Sure, when dealing with regex i often use https://regex101.com/ where the syntax enlightening is a very nice help. I put your text example in the bottom and try to match for what need to be lowercased: `.*?{` was my first shoot, it works for the first but is to greedy for the next. So i add a brace `}.*?{` which works for all but first and last... Finally gave it a brace exclusion condition: `[^}]*?{` and it worked ;)